# Do I have to worry that root user can login into MariaDB 10.5 without password

Tags: mariadb, security, password, root

I remember when installing MySQL Server 8.0, or in some database setups, there are warnings about no password login. Should I worry about this? I think if someone gets access to `root` user on my `debian` they can reset root password of MariaDB. What is the real answer here? I appreciate doc reference.

Comment: A reference is the [MariaDB Knowledge base article on Unix socket authentication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#is-it-secure) including the some tradeoffs. A person with a root unix password on a machine always has the ability to reset [any] MariaDB user password (usually by restarting MariaDB but not always).

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have only **localhost** access.

When  the attacker has somehow direct baccess to your server, it isn't that much important, but will still remain a nuisance for the hacker.

When you let access from outside the computer, it is **vital** that there is a **strong** password, which lets casual users not gain full access to the hole database.

Overall, yes make a passowrd

Comment: But I guess root access is done through a socket plugin so it might not be accessible even when remote access is granted

Comment: socket and name pipes work only on a local computer, but as i said when a hacker has local access, he cqan circumvent every security meassure. So a password is only  a nuisance